# nginx: 502 bad gateway while using node.js varnish and stunnel

Tags: nginx, varnish, node.js, stunnel

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.exratione.com/2012/08/websockets-over-ssl-stunnel-varnish-nginx-nodejs/), and everything seems to run OK, except for my nginx setup. My `node.js` application runs on port 1337, varnish runs on port 80, stunnel on 443 and nginx on 8080.

I can reach my app correctly when i specify the port `https://example.com:1337` but all I get when visiting `https://example.com` is a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

This is the output of my nginx log:

```
2012/08/25 14:13:59 [error] 6049#0: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://app_example/", host: "example.com"
2012/08/25 14:14:02 [error] 6049#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:1337/", host: "example.com"
```

and this is my nginx config file for that domain:

```
upstream example.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:1337;
}

server {
    server_name  example.com;
    listen 8080;
    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://example.com;
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I'm running:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- nginx/1.1.19
- stunnel 4.42
- varnish-3.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing.. that link said they are only using nginx for static files and html files for the website. You are trying to proxy nodejs/websockets over nginx.

So why does that website say not to do that? Mainly because websockets are not supported in nginx in a stable release.

Websockets are a 1.1 spec and nginx is only 1.0 spec. Now that said.. you can compile in like tcp_proxy for nginx but just proxy it with varnish like that url pointed out. It does not make a lot of sense to go

varnish->nginx->node

just do

varnish -> node